# IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable for double and if 'for' statement

Tags: python, numpy, if-statement, for-loop

My main aim is to print out the values of one variable which is in a double `for loop`  and under an  `if-statement`but however I tend to get an error `IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.` Here is my codes

```
import numpy as np

nR = 133
nP  = 255
Pmin = 0.09
Pmax = 20.0
dTime = 0.005

g = np.zeros((nR+1, nP+1), dtype=np.float64)
E01 = np.zeros(nR+1)
LnP = np.zeros(nP+1)


n = nR - 1
l = nP - 1

LnPmax = np.log(Pmax)
LnPmin = np.log(Pmin)
dLnP = (LnPmax - LnPmin)/(l-1)
odt = 1/dTime

for i in range(1, n):
    T1  = E01[i]*dTime
    for k in range(1, l):
        LnPa = T1 + LnP[k]
        ka = int((LnPa - LnPmin)/dLnP + 1)
        if LnPa <= LnPmin:
            ha = 0.0
        elif LnPa >= LnPmax:
            ha = 0.0
        else:
            ha = g[i][ka] + (g[i][ka+1] - g[i][ka])*(LnPa - LnPa[ka])/dLnP
            print ha
```

whenever i try to `print ha` I get an error `IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable`, I have looked up to other solution on `stackoverflow` and `google` but it was to no avail perhaps anyone could help me, I will appreciate `:)`

Comment: The code you posted has bad indentation--the lines after `for i in range(1, n):` should be indented to make them part of the for loop. Correct your indentation then get back to us.

Comment: That's right, the indentations seems to be a problem and the list/array `LnP` is not defined `Line 24`.

Comment: I have fixed the indentation, so it should be fine now @RoryDaulton,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your next-to-last line, you have the sub-expression

```
LnPa - LnPa[ka]
```

That first reference to `LnPa` is fine, since that is a float variable, but the second is not. You are trying to treat that float variable as a list or some-such with `LnPa[ka]`, by indexing it with `ka`. I do not know what you intend (you really need to add comments and make your variable names more descriptive), so I can't recommend a particular correction. But somehow get rid of `LnPa[ka]`.

Also, the last line `print ha` does not work in python 3.x. If you replace it with

```
print(ha)
```

it will work in any version of python.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Rory, It now worked when I happened to convert  `LnPa[ka]` to a float

Comment: On this site, show your appreciation by upvoting all the useful answers. You do that by clicking the up-arrow at the top-left of the answer. In addition accept the best answer by clicking the checkmark near the top-left of the answer. That is better than saying thanks in a comment.